# CKFinder 3 with Nginx configuration

Tags: php, nginx, ckeditor4.x, ckfinder

I tried to integrate CKFinder 3 with CKEditor 4.

This is my config:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', {
    filebrowserBrowseUrl: 'http://localhost:8888/build/blog/admin/ckfinder/ckfinder.html'
});
```

Here is the result when I try to browse the files on the server:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqqrQ.png)

I see the path is correct but I can not select any files. I think I need to do something else with Nginx configurations.

Any hints for me? Many thanks!